# wpf changeable image in menuitem.icon

Tags: wpf, image, dynamic, menuitem

I'm trying to implement an language menu in my code, but i don't get it to work that my language button shows me the correct image for the active language.

The code i'm actualing trying with, is not correct. But i don't know how to change it that it is working:

```
<MenuItem Click="LangMouseLeftButtonUp" ContextMenuOpening="LangMouseRightButtonUp" x:Name="LangImageIcon">
   <MenuItem.Icon>
      <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
         <Style.Triggers>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Language.ActualLanguage}" Value="EN">
              <Setter Property="Icon">
                 <Setter.Value>
                   <Image Source="Resources/United_Kingdom.png" Height="20" />
                 </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
           </DataTrigger>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Language.ActualLanguage}" Value="DE">
              <Setter Property="Icon">
                 <Setter.Value>
                   <Image Source="Resources/Germany.png" Height="20" />
                 </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
           </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
       </Style> 
   </MenuItem.Icon>
   <MenuItem.ContextMenu>
      <ContextMenu>
          <MenuItem Header="Deutsch" Click="MenuLanguageDE_Click"/>
           <MenuItem Header="Englisch" Click="MenuLanguageEN_Click"/>
      </ContextMenu>
   </MenuItem.ContextMenu>
</MenuItem>
```

The language class i'm using as data trigger gives me the actual langeuage and i want to set an image depending on this value. I don't want to is C# code for this, as i think wpf can do this with databinding and thats the cleanest approach.

I know the style value is not correct here. The setter property is wrong too. At least the xaml designer told me this. 
At the moment i try to learn the principles of xaml code and, yeah, i think for this problem i don't know them. ;) So, please be patient.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I reqorked the code that xaml-designer don't kills me, but the image is not displayed. It shows "System.Windows.Style" instead.

Comment: You have to put your `Style` in `MenuItem.Style` not `MenuItem.Icon`

Comment: @Coops give me some minutes. i will create an mcve so that you can see it.
But i have to build it from scratch though the main project is way bigger.

Comment: @nosale I tried it to put the style under menuitem, but it didn't work. I think i have to change more than only moving it around. I will try...

Answer (score 0):

Goddammit i was so close.

@nosale You gave the correct hint. After changing the menuitem.icon to menuitem.style everything works well!

```
<MenuItem Click="LangMouseLeftButtonUp" ContextMenuOpening="LangMouseRightButtonUp" x:Name="LangImageIcon">
    <MenuItem.Style>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Language.ActualLanguage}" Value="EN">
                    <Setter Property="Icon">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Image Source="Resources/United_Kingdom.png" Height="20" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Language.ActualLanguage}" Value="DE">
                    <Setter Property="Icon">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Image Source="Resources/Germany.png" Height="20" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Style>
    <MenuItem.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Deutsch" Click="MenuLanguageDE_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Englisch" Click="MenuLanguageEN_Click"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </MenuItem.ContextMenu>
</MenuItem>
```

Thanks for the help!!!